# API to set the speed of a Motion using a Mechanim Blend tree?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am writing some editor extensions which setup big complex mechanim blend trees and state machines. I have no problem creating layers, states, and attaching motions to blend trees via editor scripts, etc...

However, I can not find any calls that allow me to setup a Motion's speed setting. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

While there's no direct API call to set the speed of a motion in a blend tree it is possible to do so via Unity's SerializedObject/SerializedProperty API.  Something like this ought to do it:

```
var serialised = new SerializedObject(blendTree);
var children = serialised.FindProperty("m_Childs");
var child = children.GetArrayElementAtIndex(0);
var timeScale = child.FindPropertyRelative("m_TimeScale");
timeScale.floatValue = speed;
serialised.ApplyModifiedProperties();
```

Answer (score -1):

I think what you're looking for is AnimatorState.speedParameter :
https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Animations.AnimatorState-speedParameter.html

This thread show how to use it and has also interesting workarounds in case it's not enough https://forum.unity3d.com/threads/mecanim-change-animation-speed-of-specific-animation-or-layers.160395/page-2

Comment: I'm afraid this isn't quite right. You are referring to the speed setting of the state and not the individual motion's within that state. I have blend trees with 5-6 motions in them which all need to be set at different values rather than the state the blend tree belongs to

Comment: I see, have you seen this : You can access ChildMotions within your blendtree (BlendTree.children) and then you have access to the timescale of each motion. https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Animations.BlendTree.html

Comment: That would do it! Big thanks. Although I am pretty critical of this API, nowhere have I ever had to do an operation like this: Collection.AddElement.  Collection.GetSameElementOfDifferentType, ChildElementType.NewProperty = value; It would also be fair and realistic to expect the tool tip to match the name of this property like the rest of the editor

Comment: BlendTree.children returns a *copy* of the data, so you can read it but altering it has no effect :-(.